# Need an explanation on simple code

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#ID').on('click', function() {
    if(!CommonUtil.compareDateById('startDt','endDt',false, false, true)) {
        return false;           
    }
    var cnt = 0;

    if(!CommonUtil.isNullOrEmptyById('startDt'))     { cnt++; }

if(cnt == 0) {
        CommonUtil.setFocusById('srchWord','<spring:message code="confirm.input" arguments="XXXX"/>');
        return false;
```

So if I click on #ID, following logic occurs.
And my question is what does
    var cnt = 0;

```
if(!CommonUtil.isNullOrEmptyById('startDt')) {
    cnt++;
}
```

mean?

The function of `isNullOrEmptyById` is following:

```
isNullOrEmptyById: function(id) {
    var value = this.getTrimValueById(id);

    return this.isNullOrEmpty(value);
},
```

But what does

```
cnt++;
```

do in here??

Comment: Incrementing a counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an `if` conditional block:

```
if(!CommonUtil.isNullOrEmptyById('startDt')) {
  cnt++;
}
```

So if `CommonUtil.isNullOrEmptyById('startDt')` resolves to `false`, then the condition resolves to `true` and the code in the block is executed:

```
cnt++;
```

[The `++` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) increments the value.  So whatever numeric value is in `cnt` will be incremented by 1.

In the overall context of the code, it seems to be treating `cnt` as more of a boolean than an integer, though.  Unless there's more code outside of this example, this can be simplified by using this condition for the last conditional block instead of using `cnt` and then checking its value.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually unnecessary. Since the cnt is only incremented once it's value is either 0 or 1. Instead you could just get rid of all that and use isNullOrEmptyById function.

```
if(!CommonUtil.isNullOrEmptyById('startDt')){
   CommonUtil.setFocusById('srchWord','<spring:message code="confirm.input" arguments="XXXX"/>');
   return false;  
}
```

Comment: so according to the code, if StartDt is not Null or empty, cnt increments to 1, correct??

Comment: and if it is  Null or empty, cnt stays 0. So spring message occurs?